# Upgrade Process of 14.xx on Intel CPU VM Selects AMD Packages

Tags: upgrade

The title pretty much says it all.  I'm using a MacBook Pro, 2.3 MHz I7 running OS X 10.12.1 and Parallels Pro 12.  I just happen to notice all the AMD packages when the upgrade process opened a terminal window.

Haven't yet dared to try to run it as the upgrade appears to have hung after starting to recover journal - it reached the clean/files/size line before hanging.

Why would the upgrade pick AMD architecture instead of Intel?  Is the a fix short of deleting the virtual machine and starting back with 16.04 as a new install?

Comment: That is actually just an instruction set definition.  AMD or Intel will both read the AMD64 instruction set.  Second paragraph here explains more:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Comment: Which packages exactly are you referring to? Please edit your question to name them (or a few of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"AMD64" is just the name used by Debian/Ubuntu to refer to the x86_64 architecture (the latter being the more vendor-neutral way to refer to it). It's just called AMD64 because AMD designed and implemented it before Intel adopted it as well.